# Of which or of which the

Tags: british-english

Would you say, "a flat of which windows were broken" or "a flat of which the windows were broken"? Of course the best solution is "A flat the windows of which" or "whose windows".

Comment: Could you explain why your 'best solution' of *whose windows* isn't good enough? A complete example sentence might help.

Comment: @JimMack That would work if what is intended is that all the windows are broken.  If only some of the are, we need another way round it.

Comment: You kind of supply the answer yourself. Note how you said the best solution is "a flat the windows of which" and not "a flat windows of which". So you do want to say "the". And so if you change the word order, you want to keep it.

Answer (score -1):

It depends whether what is being said is that **all** the windows or only **some** of them were broken.

“The windows” will tend to mean all of them.  The only exception would be certain collective nouns, like ‘the people’.  “The people voted for Brexit” does not mean that **all** the people so voted, though pro-brexit activists are happy to give that impression.

> I have bought a flat of which the windows are broken.

This means that they all are broken.

> I have bought a flat of which windows are broken.

This is incorrect.  We can understand, if we think about it, that it must mean that **some** windows are broken.  But this needs saying.

> I have bought a flat of which some windows are broken.

Strangely enough, there is a way of saying it without its being possible to tell whether all, most or just a few windows are broken.

> I have bought a flat with broken windows.

This is consistent with its being the case that some or, even in the absence of the definite article, all of the windows that are said to be broken.  All that is certain is that there are more than one of them.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR: You should use

> a flat of which the windows were broken

if they broke all the windows, and

> a flat in which windows were broken

if they just broke some of the windows.

The way to figure these things out is to unwind the sentences.
Would you say

> Somebody broke the windows of my flat,

or

> *Somebody broke windows of my flat.

When I look at these sentences, it seems to me that the first one implies they broke *all* the windows. The second one is awkward, because *windows of my flat* sounds like it refers to all the windows, but if you were trying to talk about all the windows, you would use *the*. If they just broke some of the windows, you would use the preposition *in*.

> Somebody broke windows *in* my flat.

Turning these back into relative clauses,

you get *a flat of which the windows are broken* or *a flat in which windows were broken*, as I say at the beginning of this answer.